# How can I mock pathlib.Path.open and pathlib.path.unlink with the same syntax?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I use `pathlib.Path.open()` and `pathlib.Path.unlink()` in my productive code. The `unittest` for that work. But I use two different ways to `patch()`. One with `@patch` decorator and one with a context manager `with mock.patch()`.

I would like to have `@patch` only like this.

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pathlib.Path.unlink')
    @mock.patch('pathlib.Path.open')
    def test_foobar(self, mock_open, mock_unlink):
```

But the real code currenty looks like this

```
import unittest
from unittest import mock
import pathlib

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pathlib.Path.unlink')
    def test_foobar(self, mock_unlink):
        # simulated CSV file
        opener = mock.mock_open(read_data='A;B\n1;2')

        with mock.patch('pathlib.Path.open', opener):
            result = validate_csv(file_path=pathlib.Path('foo.csv'))
            self.assertTrue(result)
```

Technical my problem here is that I do not know how to add my CSV content to `mock_open` when using the `@patch` decorator.

It could look like this:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('pathlip.Path.open')
    @mock.patch('pathlib.Path.unlink')
    def test_foobar(self, mymock_unlink, mymock_open):
        # simulated CSV file
        opener = mock.mock_open(read_data='A;B\n1;2')

        # QUESTION: How do I bring 'opener' and 'mymock_open'
        # together now?

        result = validate_csv(file_path=pathlib.Path('foo.csv'))
        self.assertTrue(result)
```

But the goal of my question is to improve readability and maintainability of the code. Using two decorators would reduce the indention. Choosing one way (decorators or context managers) would IMHO be easier to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## For learning purposes

Q: How do I bring 'opener' and 'mymock_open' together now?

A: Assign `side_effect` and `return_value` of `mymock_open` to those of `opener`.

```py
@mock.patch('pathlib.Path.open')
@mock.patch('pathlib.Path.unlink')
def test_foobar(self, mymock_unlink, mymock_open):
    # simulated CSV file
    opener = mock.mock_open(read_data='A;B\n1;2')

    # QUESTION: How do I bring 'opener' and 'mymock_open'
    # together now?
    mymock_open.side_effect = opener.side_effect    # +
    mymock_open.return_value = opener.return_value  # +

    result = validate_csv(file_path=pathlib.Path('foo.csv'))
    opener.assert_not_called()          # +
    mymock_open.assert_called_once()    # +
    mymock_unlink.assert_called_once()  # +
    self.assertTrue(result)
```

But this is hardly a readability improvement.

## Both using decorators

```py
@mock.patch('pathlib.Path.open', new_callable=lambda: mock.mock_open(read_data='A;B\n1;2'))  # +
@mock.patch('pathlib.Path.unlink')
def test_foobar(self, mock_unlink, mock_open):
    result = validate_csv(file_path=pathlib.Path('foo.csv'))
    mock_open.assert_called_once()    # +
    mock_unlink.assert_called_once()  # +
    self.assertTrue(result)
```

Passing just `mock.mock_open(read_data='A;B\n1;2')` (as positional argument `new`) instead of `new_callable=lambda: ...` works too, but then `@mock.patch` won't pass `mock_open` to `test_foobar`.

## Both using context managers

```py
def test_foobar(self):
    # simulated CSV file
    opener = mock.mock_open(read_data='A;B\n1;2')

    with mock.patch('pathlib.Path.unlink') as mock_unlink,\
            mock.patch('pathlib.Path.open', opener) as mock_open:  # +
        self.assertIs(mock_open, opener)  # +
        result = validate_csv(file_path=pathlib.Path('foo.csv'))
        mock_open.assert_called_once()    # +
        mock_unlink.assert_called_once()  # +
        self.assertTrue(result)
```

Notice that `mock_open` is the same instance as `opener`.

---

## Verifying the solutions

Sample implementation of `validate_csv` for a minimal, reproducible example:

```py
def validate_csv(file_path):
    """
    :param pathlib.Path file_path:
    :rtype: bool
    """
    with file_path.open() as f:
        data = f.read()
    file_path.unlink()
    return data == 'A;B\n1;2'
```